# GPU for Blender- RX 570 or Nvidia/CPU- Ryzen or Intel?

Tags: hardware

CPU

I've seen that ryzen 5 3600 outperforms my other two choices i5 9600k and i5 8400 but is it issue-free with Blender like the intel ones I mentioned?

GPU

I've also seen that rx 570 outperforms a gtx 1650 (Which is the best in my budget). But is Blender as compatible with an AMD GPU as it is with an Nvidia GPU?

Comment: I'm using Blender on Linux with Vega 64 (and a Ryzen 7 2700x), there were some issues getting opencl working (and some unrelated GPU crashes) but they've mostly been resolved on the latest version.

Comment: Hardware questions were eventually allowed, and I wasn't aware of it. Reopening for now, sorry for the misunderstanding.